# Correctly send a 200 response with an empty body to a WebHook. Minimal example provided

Tags: php, webhooks, xero-api

Following some examples online, I am to return a 200 response for a correctly signed payload, and a 401 response for an incorrectly signed, or malformed payload.

The following minimal example has been tested.

The signature is being generated correctly, and the `checkHash()` function identifies the correctly signed/formed payloads.

The feedback I am getting from the endpoint is **Response contained a body**.  The advice given [here](https://community.xero.com/developer/discussion/73651430) is to strip everything from the body of the response -but as far as I can see  all I am return is the literal response as an echo i.e. **200** or **401**.

```
$key = 'abcSomeKey';    
$rawPayload = file_get_contents("php://input");
checkHash();

function getSignature() {
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $rawPayload, $key, true));
}

function checkHash() {
    $signature = getSignature();

    if($signature === $_SERVER['HTTP_X_XERO_SIGNATURE']) {
        echo 200;
    }
    else {
        echo 401;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know php well enough, but there were two errors.  The signature validation wasn't working as intended inside the function block.  The `$rawPayload` was an empty string inside the `getSignature()` function.

Further, I was naively returning the response code which is correctly formatted below.

```
$key = "someKey";
$rawPayload = file_get_contents("php://input");
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $rawPayload, $key, true));
$authKey = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_XERO_SIGNATURE'];

if($signature === $authKey)
{
    http_response_code(200);
}   
else
{
    http_response_code(401);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, with a service.

here was what I found out to be true:

```
$key = "someKey";
$rawPayload = file_get_contents("php://input");
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $rawPayload, $key, true));
$authKey = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_XERO_SIGNATURE'];
if($signature === $authKey)
{
    http_response_code(200);
}   
else
{
    http_response_code(401);
}
```

Doing this: `base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $rawPayload, $key, true));`
resulted in a binary code because of the `hash_hmac` having the `true` on the end.
also the base64 changed the `hash_hmac`, so I had to do this with mine:

```
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $rawPayload, $key);
```

That worked for me.